# double* array, vs double* pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, double

How come double* array can be used as an array? I always see the asterisk as a pointer, how come it could be used as an array? 
Will anyone provide an example how it could be used as a double[], and when it is only a pointer.

Comment: I think you forgot to add a language tag such as *C*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that "used as an array" means the subscript operator `[]`?

The reason is that in C and C++, the subscript operator actually performs pointer addition.  It doesn't work on arrays at all, it causes the array name to decay to a pointer, and then pointer arithmetic occurs.

For all built-in types,

```
x[y]
```

is defined as

```
*(x + y)
```

It doesn't matter which of `x` and `y` is the pointer (or array decaying to pointer) and which is the offset.

Comment: @user3345589: No.  It means that most of the ways you can use an array, you're actually using a pointer to the first element.  The conversion, called "array to pointer decay", is implicit.  In fact, probably the only case you'll encounter when it doesn't decay is with `sizeof`.

Comment: And & operator. And in C++, when bound to a reference.

Comment: @user3521733: Indeed, those are additional cases.  But they are not commonly encountered.